# Installing ifuse with Homebrew results in ERROR message

Tags: macos, homebrew, fuse

I am just starting to install these binaries to access my iPhone and running into an error when trying to install `ifuse`.

I installed `osxfuse` v 3.11.2 using Homebrew first. I have two versions loaded in System Preferences:

FUSE 3.11.2 and macFuse 4.1.0

I also installed [fuse osx 1.9.0](https://fuse-open.github.io/)

The error I am receiving is:

> Error: ifuse has been disabled because it requires FUSE!

```
Sun Apr 18 05:18:54
iMac191:Homebrew john$ brew install fuse
==> Downloading https://github.com/fuse-open/fuse-studio/releases/download/1.9.0/fuse_osx_1_9_0.pkg
==> Downloading from https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/133309840/5134f00e-6266-11e8-93cc-f1c5a91a10eb?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIW
######################################################################## 100.0%0
==> Installing Cask fuse
==> Running installer for fuse; your password may be necessary.
Package installers may write to any location; options such as `--appdir` are ignored.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
installer: Package name is Fuse
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install was successful.
  fuse was successfully installed!


Sun Apr 18 09:33:33
iMac191:Homebrew john$ brew info fuse
fuse: 1.9.0
https://fuse-open.github.io/
/usr/local/Caskroom/fuse/1.9.0 (156.0MB)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/fuse.rb
==> Names
Fuse Studio
Fuse Open
Fuse Fusetools
==> Description
Visual desktop tool suite for working with the Fuse framework
==> Artifacts
fuse_osx_1_9_0.pkg (Pkg)
==> Analytics
install: 1,029 (30 days), 1,703 (90 days), 3,605 (365 days)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

as per TBR & dcmorse's advice, but just spelling it out further...

1. make sure you have osx/macFUSE installed (if not -- `$ brew install macfuse`)
2. get formula location: `$ brew formula $PACKAGE_OF_INTEREST`
3. open formula in editor-of-choice (e.g. `$ vi $( brew formula $PACKAGE_OF_INTEREST )`) and comment out the section containing `disable`

in my case, that means changing to:

```
  # on_macos do                                                                 
  #   disable! date: "2021-04-08", because: "requires FUSE"                     
  # end
```

4. install as usual: `$ brew install $PACKAGE_OF_INTEREST`

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

osxfuse was removed from homebrew/core recently:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/94072

As a result all formulas depending on it have been disabled.

My current understanding is that you'd have to either use a non-core formula or download the formula locally and remove the `disable` line.

Sorry for not having a more satisfying answer. I just ran into this myself with `sshfs` and installed packages from outside of homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

The brew package `osxfuse` seems to not be supported post v3.11.2.

Viewing it in the System Preferences pane shows that an update is available - [v4.1.2 at time of writing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj9aC.png)

Actually upgrading via the GUI throws an error, which then breaks future GUI interactions. A `brew reinstall osxfuse` will reinstall v3.11.2.

I removed `osxfuse` with `brew uninstall osxfuse` and installed
`macfuse` instead, resulting in [System Preferences showing macFUSE installed to latest version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MEEI.png)

As per miriam's post, commenting out the *"disable!"* lines from the formula was the final step in allowing the install to work.

```sh
$ vi `brew formula ifuse`

...

  #on_macos do
  #  disable! date: "2021-04-08", because: "requires closed-source macFUSE"
  #end

...

$ brew install ifuse
```

Answer (score 2):

This Bash function uses TBR's suggestion and removes the "disable!" line from a package's formula:

```
brew-install-fuse() {
    local nom="$1";
    local X="${TMP:-/tmp}/${nom}.rb";
    brew formula "$nom" \
        | xargs cat \
        | gsed -E 's/^(\s+disable\!.+FUSE)/#\1/g' > "$X" \
        && echo "Installing from \"$X\"";
    #cat "$X"; echo "X=$X"; return;
    brew install "$X";
    declare -l D=y \
        && read -t 5 -N 1 -p "Delete \"$X\"? [Y/n]: " D;
    if [[ "$D" == "y" ]]; then
        echo "Deleting \"$X\"";
        rm -f "$X";
    fi;
}
```

Use it in lieu of `brew install <pkg depending on fuse>`, like:

```
brew-install-fuse <pkg depending on fuse>
```

Your mileage may vary.