# I changed a file incorrectly in vi when trying to install ifuse on OSX and don't know how to get the original back

Tags: homebrew, vi, macfuse

I'm very inexperienced, and was following directions here ---

[Installing ifuse with Homebrew results in ERROR message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67155330/installing-ifuse-with-homebrew-results-in-error-message/68091613#68091613?newreg=e6e32ef38751455798840f28cd8c9dbe)

I believe I made some unintended changes when I was editing the file in

```
$ vi `brew formula ifuse`
```

without understanding what I was doing. When I went to install ifuse,  it just give me an error.  Is there any way to get back to the original file/undo my edits?

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew formulas are in a local git repository. You can restore the original formula by typing:

```
cd `brew --prefix`/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
git checkout ifuse.rb
```